# how to generate ramdom values by given list and attach to dictinoary with replacement

Tags: python-3.x

```
    a=['1100001', '1100010', '1100011', '1100100', '1100101', '1100110', '1100111']
    b=[51, 51, 52, 52]
    c={}
```

In this program generate random values by taking list a  In Dictonary assign b as keys and random numbers as values with replacement

Comment: You want to randomly select an item from `a` for each item in `b`?  Is this selection with or without replacement?

Comment: it is very unclear what you are trying to do, can you be a little more descriptive and possibly walk through a partial example?

Comment: can you tell me with replacement

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` together `b` with a [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) from `a` of size `len(b)`

```
from random import sample

a=['1100001', '1100010', '1100011', '1100100', '1100101', '1100110', '1100111']
b=[51, 52, 53]

c = dict(zip(b, sample(a, len(b))))

print(c)
# {51: '1100100', 52: '1100110', 53: '1100111'}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you asked. But this might be the solution you are looking for.

```
c[b[0]] = random.choice(a)
c[b[1]] = random.choice(a)
c[b[2]] = random.choice(a)

print(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid your question is not perfectly clear but as I'm reading it, I'm getting that you want to make the values in list b keys and get 3 random values from list a that you assign to the keys.
You can easily do this by using the random module:

```
import random
```

Then you can assign a random value from list a for each value of list b to a dictionary:

```
for i in b:
    c[i] = random.choice(a)
```

This will add every value from list b as keys and assign a random string from list a as the value.